# Text change event inside listview in android

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I am new to android and I have a editText inside the listview what I want when the user puts some text or value into the editText this value should get displayed into a textview inside same listitem.I tried to get it done in getView of the custom adapter but its not working for me.My code is like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_style_task
                    , parent, false);
        }

        LItem p = getProduct(position);


          tvAQuantity=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAQuantity ))  ;
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvMaterial )).setText(p.getMName() );
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTask )).setText(p.getTName() );
          tvBQuantity=((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvBQuantity ))  ;
        tvBQuantity.setText(p.getBQ());
          etQuantity=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.etTaskQuantity);
        etQuantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                if(Integer.parseInt(s.toString())<=Integer.parseInt(tvBQuantity.getText().toString()))
                {
                    tvAQuantity.setText(s.toString());

                }
                else
                {

                    tvAQuantity.setText(tvBQuantity.getText());

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

    //  CheckBox cbBuy = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        //cbBuy.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckChangList);
    //  cbBuy.setTag(position);
    //  cbBuy.setChecked(p.selected);
        return view;
    }
```

Need your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 Alternatives are:

1. You have to update respected string into your model class which is to be displayed into textview.
2. You can call `notifyDataSetChanged();` after setText() method in your adapter.This will refresh your List View.

Answer (score 1):

Instead setting text to `TextView` try updating string value in your list model. You are facing this issue because your model is not getting updated on textchange event.

```
 if(Integer.parseInt(s.toString())<=Integer.parseInt(tvBQuantity.getText().toString()))
            {
                //update string value in your model.
                //tvAQuantity.setText(s.toString());

            }
            else
            {
                //update string value in your model.
                //tvAQuantity.setText(tvBQuantity.getText());

            }
```